# Craft 3 - Programatically get all the values contained in a field of type category

Tags: categories, craft3, elementquery

I want to programmatically get all the values contained in a field of type **category**.

I am doing this on `Elements::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT`.

If I dump `$event->element->getFieldValue('productTheme')` I get the field but I did't find how to go from there.

My final goal is to have the categories from the category field in an array (not all the categories in the category group, but only those selected in the field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field contains an object of type `ElementQuery` in order to get all `Categories` you'll need to execute it.

```
$categories = $element->getfieldValue('productTheme')->all();
$categoryTitles = [];
for($categories as $category){
    $categoryTitles[] = $category->title;
}
```

Please read the [documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/relations.html)